# How to pass mysql commands to ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, mysql, processbuilder

This is what I have:

```
List<String> restoreCmds = new ArrayList<>();
restoreCmds.add("mysql");
restoreCmds.add("-h" + host);
restoreCmds.add("-u" + login);
restoreCmds.add("-p" + pass);
restoreCmds.add("-e 'source dump.sql'");
restoreCmds.add(targetDB);

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(restoreCmds);
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
Process pr = pb.start();

int exitVal = pr.waitFor()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''source dump.sql'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add quote for source.

I changed the line to following and its working for me.

```
restoreCmds.add("-e source dump.sql");
```

Answer (score 0):

The -e option is used to directly execute the specified command, like you can see in the manual:

> --execute=statement, -e statement
>
> Execute the statement and quit. Disables --force and history file. The default output format is like that produced with --batch.

You should use input redirect to use a source file with sql to execute.

WARNING: in addition, you should specify the name of the database you want to act on.